# Problem with steam game and mono after upgrade 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: games, steam, mono

I was playing a steam game last week, no issue. Then I upgraded from Ubuntu Mate 15.04 to 15.10 and I'm getting errors.

Below is the log file. Most of it looks like gibberish to me, but mono seems to be causing a fatal problem.
Anybody who knows what to do with it? Can I downgrade mono back to the previous version? Not sure how to do this so any help is appreciated.

> Selecting FBConfig GLX_FBCONFIG_ID=330 GLX_BUFFER_SIZE=32
>   GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER=1 GLX_RED_SIZE=8 GLX_GREEN_SIZE=8 GLX_BLUE_SIZE=8
>   GLX_ALPHA_SIZE=8 GLX_DEPTH_SIZE=24 GLX_STENCIL_SIZE=8
>   GLX_SAMPLES_ARB=0 GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB=0 GLX_CONFIG_CAVEAT=NONE
>
> Desktop is 1366 x 768 @ 60 Hz GPU_MEMORY_INFO_DEDICATED_VIDMEM_NVX:
>   1048576 OpenGL: Version: OpenGL 4.5 [4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.63] Renderer:
>   GeForcERROR: ld.so: object
>   '/home/jan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from
>   LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>   Stacktrace:
>
> Native stacktrace:
>
> /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist_Data/Mono/x86/libmono.so(+0x894bb)
>   [0xf38204bb] /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist_Data/Mono/x86/libmono.so(+0x219c3)
>   [0xf37b89c3] [0xf7780b80]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__strcpy_chk+0x40) [0xf72993a0]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(+0x297f3) [0xef3377f3]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2(snd_device_name_hint+0x427)
>   [0xef338b17] /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8fc1225]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8fc1548]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8fc15b0]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8fa5ecf]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x87468a0]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8746eeb]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x874b2af]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x84272ca]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x842ed0c]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x842ef5a]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8094a47]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x80a8624]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8347ffa]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x8084558]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xde) [0xf71b972e]
>   /home/jan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/AdVenture
>   Capitalist/adventure-capitalist.x86() [0x808da65]
>
> Debug info from gdb:
>
> ================================================================= 
>   Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a 
>   fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used 
>   by your application.
>
> =================================================================
>
> Preloaded type GtkListStore Preloaded type GtkWindow Preloaded type
>   GtkVBox Preloaded type GtkImage Preloaded type GtkNotebook Preloaded
>   type GtkHBox Preloaded type GtkFrame Preloaded type GtkAlignment
>   Preloaded type GtkTreeView Preloaded type GtkLabel Preloaded type
>   GtkCheckButton Preloaded type GtkScrolledWindow Preloaded type
>   GtkComboBox Couldn't find OnScreenSelectorQuit in main module;
>   checking child Couldn't find OnScreenSelectorOK in main module;
>   checking child Couldn't find OnScreenSelectorQuit in main module;
>   checking child Couldn't find OnInputListRowActivated in main module;
>   checking child e_multisample GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
>   GL_ARB_texture_view GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_transform_feedback2
>   GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced
>   GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
>   GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
>   GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit
>   GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
>   GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader
>   GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev
>   GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_draw_buffers
>   GL_ATI_texture_float GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once GL_S3_s3tc
>   GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_bindable_uniform
>   GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
>   GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract
>   GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_Cg_shader GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test
>   GL_EXT_direct_state_access GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced
>   GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
>   GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats
>   GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
>   GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_geometry_shader4
>   GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_gpu_shader4
>   GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
>   GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object
>   GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
>   GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_secondary_color
>   GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_separate_specular_color
>   GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
>   GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
>   GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object
>   GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
>   GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
>   GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp
>   GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3
>   GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_integer
>   GL_EXT_texture_lod GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp
>   GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
>   GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_texture_storage
>   GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_timer_query GL_EXT_transform_feedback2
>   GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
>   GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_EXT_x11_sync_object
>   GL_EXT_import_sync_object GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip
>   GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_KHR_context_flush_control
>   GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_KHR_robustness
>   GL_KTX_buffer_region GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect
>   GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect_count GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced
>   GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_command_list GL_NV_compute_program5
>   GL_NV_conditional_render GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color GL_NV_copy_image
>   GL_NV_depth_buffer_float GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_NV_draw_texture
>   GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility GL_NV_ES3_1_compatibility
>   GL_NV_explicit_multisample GL_NV_fence GL_NV_float_buffer
>   GL_NV_fog_distance GL_NV_fragment_program
>   GL_NV_fragment_program_option GL_NV_fragment_program2
>   GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage GL_NV_geometry_shader4
>   GL_NV_gpu_program4 GL_NV_gpu_program4_1 GL_NV_gpu_program5
>   GL_NV_gpu_program5_mem_extended GL_NV_gpu_program_fp64
>   GL_NV_gpu_shader5 GL_NV_half_float GL_NV_light_max_exponent
>   GL_NV_multisample_coverage GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint
>   GL_NV_occlusion_query GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil
>   GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2
>   GL_NV_path_rendering GL_NV_pixel_data_range GL_NV_point_sprite
>   GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_NV_register_combiners
>   GL_NV_register_combiners2 GL_NV_shader_atomic_counters
>   GL_NV_shader_atomic_float GL_NV_shader_buffer_load
>   GL_NV_shader_storage_buffer_object GL_NV_texgen_reflection
>   GL_NV_texture_barrier GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc
>   GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_NV_texture_multisample
>   GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_NV_texture_shader GL_NV_texture_shader2
>   GL_NV_texture_shader3 GL_NV_transform_feedback
>   GL_NV_transform_feedback2 GL_NV_uniform_buffer_unified_memory
>   GL_NV_vdpau_interop GL_NV_vertex_array_range GL_NV_vertex_array_range2
>   GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory
>   GL_NV_vertex_program GL_NV_vertex_program1_1 GL_NV_vertex_program2
>   GL_NV_vertex_program2_option GL_NV_vertex_program3
>   GL_NVX_conditional_render GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info
>   GL_NV_shader_thread_group GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
>   GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_SGIX_depth_texture
>   GL_SGIX_shadow GL_SUN_slice_accum  GLX Extensions: GLX_EXT_visual_info
>   GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
>   GLX_SGI_video_sync GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_EXT_swap_control
>   GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
>   GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX_ARB_create_context
>   GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile
>   GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
>   GLX_NV_delay_before_swap GLX_EXT_stereo_tree
>   GLX_ARB_context_flush_control GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_NV_float_buffer
>   GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
>   GLX_NV_multisample_coverage GLX_NV_copy_image GLX_ARB_get_proc_address
>   Setting maxVSyncInterval to 4 GL: Detected 1024 MB VRAM Initialize
>   engine version: 5.1.2f1 (afd2369b692a)

Answer (score 1):

I have installed ubuntu-desktop, this seems to have resolved the issue.

Edit:
To install ubuntu-desktop, open terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

As mentioned in the question, I was running MATE (gnome2 variant as far as I can tell), not Unity which comes in the ubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: I appreciate you Jakke for posting your self answer but as pointed by @DavidFoerster please add command to install. Is it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`?